# JS if/else trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#continue").click(function() {
        var value = jQuery('#continue').attr('value')
            alert (value);
            if (value='next'){
                jQuery('#msg_title').html('blablabla');
                jQuery('#msg').html('blablabla'');
                jQuery('#continue').attr('value','removeConfig');
                value = jQuery('#continue').attr('value');
            }
            else if (value='removeConfig') {
                jQuery('#msg_title').html('It Works!');             
            }
            else {
                alert ('Something wrong')
            }
        return false;
        });
});

</script>
```

It works well in firs `if` phase, changes button's value (as I see from alert), but doesn't make `else if` and `else` statements.

Comment: Run your JS through http://jslint.com.

Answer (score 9):

Your comparison operator is wrong: `if (value='next')` should be `if (value == 'next'){` or `if (value === 'next'){`.

Note the extra `=` signs.

Answer (score 2):

You need `==`

```
(value='next'){
```

should be:

```
(value == 'next'){
```

You are testing `if ('next') {` which is always true. Only string the evaluates to false is empty string, `""`

Answer (score 2):

Use `==`, not `=`. A single `=` is an assignment operator, which means it's assigning `"next"` to `value`, then testing if `value` is `false`, not if `value` equals `next`

Answer (score 2):

You need double equals signs as singles will return true in this case:

```
if (value =="next")
```

Single `=` is an assignment operator and double `==` is a comparison operator. Since you were using an assignment operator and setting the variable to a non falsy value the first `if` statement resolved to true.

Comment: As far as I know assignment doesn't always evaluate to true. For example `if (a = false)` will not execute the if block.

Comment: @RCE Good call, here is a fiddle to show that setting a variable to a string updates the value of the variable and returns true: http://jsfiddle.net/FMnNr/ (But setting the variable to `false` will return false).